# huggingface transformer models: KeyError: 'input_ids' message at beginning of BERT model training

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

Using the Huggingface transformer library, I am encountering a bug in the final step when I go to fine tune the BERT language model for masked language modelling task.  I am looking to fine tune it for an in domain finance corpus that model has not been trained on yet.  However, I get the following error message when I call the model to train:  KeyError: 'input_ids'.  Provided below are the steps and code I took.  Any insights are appreciated!

First, I created a dataset object from a pandas dataframe that was in turn created from a csv file with 1 column of many rows of text:

```
unlabelled_dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(unlabelled)
```

Second, I then tokenized the dataset with the following code:

```
tokenizerBERT = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')  #BERT model tokenization & check
tokenizerBERT(unlabelled_dataset['paragraphs'], padding=True, truncation=True)
tokenizerBERT.save_pretrained('tokenizers/pytorch/labelled/BERT/')
```

Third, I created a data collator as instructed:

```
data_collator_BERT = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizerBERT, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.15)
```

Next, I select my model from_pretrained to get the benefits of transfer learning:

```
model_BERT = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

Next, I passed my training args to the transformer trainer and initialize:

```
training_args_BERT = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./BERT",
    num_train_epochs=10,
    evaluation_strategy='steps',
    warmup_steps=10000,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    per_gpu_train_batch_size=64,    
)

trainer_BERT = Trainer(
    model=model_BERT,
    args=training_args_BERT,
    data_collator=data_collator_BERT,
    train_dataset=unlabelled_dataset,
)
```

Last, I call the model to train and get the error KeyError: 'input_ids'

```
trainer_BERT.train()
```

Any insights on how to debug this approach to training the model?

Provided below is the exact error message received:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-83b7063dea0b> in <module>
----> 1 trainer_BERT.train()
      2 trainer.save_model("./models/royalBERT")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, model_path, trial)
    755             self.control = self.callback_handler.on_epoch_begin(self.args, self.state, self.control)
    756 
--> 757             for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
    758 
    759                 # Skip past any already trained steps if resuming training

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    361 
    362     def __next__(self):
--> 363         data = self._next_data()
    364         self._num_yielded += 1
    365         if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    401     def _next_data(self):
    402         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 403         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    404         if self._pin_memory:
    405             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 47         return self.collate_fn(data)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py in __call__(self, examples)
    193     ) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
    194         if isinstance(examples[0], (dict, BatchEncoding)):
--> 195             examples = [e["input_ids"] for e in examples]
    196         batch = self._tensorize_batch(examples)
    197         if self.mlm:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    193     ) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
    194         if isinstance(examples[0], (dict, BatchEncoding)):
--> 195             examples = [e["input_ids"] for e in examples]
    196         batch = self._tensorize_batch(examples)
    197         if self.mlm:

KeyError: 'input_ids'
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the tokenizer is passed through the `DataCollator`, I think we have to perform tokenization on the data:

Hence, we need to perform tokenization on the data as:

```
train_dataset = tokenizer.encode(unlabeled_data, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors="pt")
trainer_BERT = Trainer(
    model=model_BERT,
    args=training_args_BERT,
    data_collator=data_collator_BERT,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
)
```

Comment: while i am entirely new to this library my understanding was that the tokenization happenned via the call below:

Comment: Yeah, we should kind of expect the tokenization to internally happen. However, it has not. For example, `["input_ids"]` should have been part of dictionary of the inputs passed to the model, which has not. More over,

Comment: Let me know if it has solved the problem. Or if you face some other problem.